# aspx.cs file not getting updated?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i added some controls in designer file but cs file not accepting those controls, it says textbox1 does not exist in current context.
i have tried these solutions:
1) convert to web application
2) recreated both files .aspx and .aspx.cs
 but it didn't solve my problem ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do your controls have the runat="server" attribute set?It would help if you could post the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to analyze the situation ....
may be because of the container (like panel) 
try like this

```
TextBox tb=(TextBox)<"container name">.FindControl("textbox1");
```

Answer (score 0):

when u are creating a new aspx page make sure u select place code in separate file.if it's ok, then after creating the aspxx file drag and drop a textbox from toolbox's standard option. then check the id of the textbox from property window. use the id like this `textbox1.Text`. if you are using html text box then make it `runat="server"` and use the id of the textbox.